# Change the user and server within single shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I wanted to perform a certain task on one server like PROD and which is pre-request of another task, once the prod task is done I wanted to start another server task consider that server as QA.

I am using a shell script in unix to perform this task as flow, currently running 2 scripts in both the server independently but I have to check it manually that one is complete or not then only I can start on another server.

Any suggestion or any reference site which can help me to accommodate both the script flow into just one.

Comment: Do the two jobs run on the same machine, or in the same shell? Just use `script1 && script2` maybe? If you can run them from a central machine, use that invocation from there.

Comment: @Corion this 2 jobs runs on the 2 different machines (prod and qa env), yes I have two scripts for each of the environment (prod and qa ) and there is no central machine for invocation, Currently, I am running both the job independently manually one after another in both the environments.

Answer (score 0):

You should focus on the first script, how it can show who it is run (can you check `$?` ?).
When both scrips are run manually without a central server, you need to look at the result of the first.
When you can write a script that can call `hostname` on both servers, you can change that script in a way it will check the result of the first server before starting the second.